# Why does my json_decode return empty?

Tags: json

I have the following JSON:

```
 a:2:{i:0;s:6:"qweqwe";i:1;s:12:"vbnvbnvbnvbn";}
```

and when I use `json_decode();` it returns `null`. Anybody some help?

Comment: please rectify your json format..

Answer (score 1):

> I have the following JSON:

No, that's not JSON. That's why.